# Android Studio Not Deploying App

Tags: android, android-studio

I currently have the latest version of Android Studio and I'm trying to deploy an app onto my phone running Android 5.0.1 Lollipop. After building, the terminal shows that the apk is being installed onto the phone and the status indicates that it is running. However, nothing shows up on my phone (no running applications and the app does not show up in the installed applications list). I've tried disabling auto-run in studio settings but it doesn't help. Any ideas why it's doing this? Also I reinstalled the adb driver just in case that was the cause. It might be helpful to note also that this happens even on the default template apps generated by studio.

Comment: Can you share your source files , including manifest, main activity. Java and activity main.xml , also add logcat

Comment: Does your app run on an emulator?

Comment: I'm using the default template files generated by Android Studio that consists of a MainActivity which contains a toolbar and a button and an textview field.

Comment: Yes the app runs on an emulator just fine. I'm having trouble deploying it on my physical device through Android Studio. Also, I forgot to mention that when I build the actual APK and install it like that, it works.

Comment: @RobertLu i think your app already running in emulator and now you attach mobile to run in mobile. so its give this problem. just close emulator or close app from emulator then try

Comment: can you post the manifiest file, make sure that you have mentioned launcher activity in manifest and check that you are setting contentview in that activity

Answer (score 0):

try to turn off the Instant Run

File - Settings - Search Instant Run , unselect all the options

Hope this would help.

Comment: I already tried that. Never mind, I found the solution. Turns out the issue was on the ADB running on my phone. Downloaded ADB insecure and gave it root access. Now the deployment is a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the '[HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/)' (version 6.3.0.3003.AF) plugin, on Android Studio Chipmunk (version 2021.2.1), was causing this.
I've disabled it and it all started working again.