# Why is Android Studio not building and deploying correct apk

Tags: android, android-studio

My issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841452/android-studio-not-deploying-app) however the app *is* deployed.

Currently on Windows when I click run in the Android Studio Gradle starts building as expected and says completed (sometimes completed with 1 warning and sometimes, depending on the situation I may get a dialog about uninstalling the previous APK)

Then the activity launches on the device or emulator as expected, but when I start testing it becomes obvious that the newest changes are not deployed. Either the installation has silently failed or an old APK from the build cache has been deployed.

I have instant run switched off but usually do not uninstall the app between running my changes, except where I have changed branches (Git) and Android Studio has told me the versions are incompatible.

Usually if the system gets into this state the only thing that helps is <kbd>Invalidate Caches/ Restart</kbd>

This is a hard issue to track, has anybody else encountered it and had success in preventing it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Instant Run?

Comment: I was just editing my question to add that, instant run is always disabled

Comment: Its not a solution, but I can suggest to switch to some branch and then switch back, and rebuild project after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to prevent this, but the following seems to work to ensure the correct APK is always installed:

1. Uninstall from device/emulator
2. Run Gradle/cleanBuildCache
3. Run Gradle/clean
4. Deploy

If you skip cleanBuildCache it fails. Clean alone doesn't appear to do enough.

I'm still looking for a better answer - post if you have one