# Android Studio debug with modified XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I use Android Studio 3.0 Beta5 and I've a problem when the application is runing on emulator (or device) and I edit the XML of layout or other XML files.

The modified files is not deployed on the emulator and remain old version.

I try to disable InstantRun.

If I rebuild project all work fine.

What I need to check to solve this problem?

P.S. Using the rebuild I solve but I need 1/2 mintutes every change to be visible on device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Android Studio not building and deploying correct apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843686/why-is-android-studio-not-building-and-deploying-correct-apk)

Comment: I've also problem with some annotation processing, like Parceler that could not find the parceled classes.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, perhaps you can post it (with the code used for parceling and unparceling)